# How can I get the time and date my PowerShell script deletes a file

Tags: powershell, date, time

I am using the following script to read a list of file names which are then deleted. Is there a way can get an output of the date and time each file is deleted?

```
$targetFolder = "D:\" $fileList = "C:\DeleteList.txt" Get-ChildItem
-Path "$targetFolder\*" -Recurse -Include @(Get-Content $fileList) | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmmm, you can pipe it to `Foreach-Object` and throw the `Remove-Item` in there, then you'll be able to just run something like `Get-Date`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AbrahamZinala would you be kind enough to give me an example?

Comment: See @Theos answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of the files that are deleted and the time of deletion by outputting an object with the file's fullname and current date.

This output can then be saved as structured CSV file

```
$targetFolder = "D:\" 
$fileList     = Get-Content -Path "C:\DeleteList.txt" 

$deleted = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetFolder -Recurse -Include $fileList | ForEach-Object {
    # output an object with the current date and the file FullName
    $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'DeletedOn'; Expression = {(Get-Date)}}, FullName
    $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf
} 

# output on screen
$deleted | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to csv file
$deleted | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\RemovedFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` safety-switch if you are satisfied with the results shown on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$targetFolder = "D:" 
$fileList = "C:\DeleteList.txt" 
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder" -Recurse -Include @(Get-Content $fileList)

# Once you have the desires files stored in the $Files variable, then run a Foreach loop. 

$Obj = @() # create an array called $Obj
Foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    # store info in hash table
    $hash = @{
        DateTime = (get-date)
        fileName = $File.name
        fullpath = $File.fullname
    }
    Write-Host "deleting file $($file.name)" -for cyan
    Remove-Item $File.fullname # *** BE VERY CAREFUL!!!***

    # record information in an array called $Obj
    $Obj += New-Object psobject -Property $hash
}

$Obj | select fileName, DateTime | Export-csv C:\...
```